# fixed div position shrinks on removal of conditional sub divs

Tags: html, css

I want to implement shopping cart div which has fixed position and covers 25-30% of the screen. Something like this.

[image]

Here is my Html file

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="position:fixed;margin-right: 6ex;">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="text-center">
            <span>WarenKorb</span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div *ngIf="this.orderedItems.length < 1">
            <p style="text-align: center;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></p> <br>
            <span class="emptybucket">Wähle leckere Gerichte aus der Karte und bestelle Dein Menü.</span>
        </div>
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of orderedItems;let i = index">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    <span>{{item.quantity}}</span>
    <span  style="color:#7d7d7d; font-size: 10px;">x</span>       
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
    <span >{{item.name}}</span></div>
        <div class="row">
            <span style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;font-style: italic;">({{item.size}})</span>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;font-style: italic;font-size: 12px;">{{getOderAdditionsText(i)}}</span></div>
</div>
    <div  class="col-sm-4" style="align-content: center;">
        <button type="button" (click)="decreaseQuantity(item)" style="background-color: white;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" (click)="increaseQuantity(item)" style="background-color: white;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
            <span class="  glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    <span>
        <a>
            <span  (click)="deleteTheItemFromOrder(item)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 pull-right">
    <span>{{item.totalPrice}}€</span>
</div>
</div>
<hr>


<div class="row">
    <span class="pull-left" style="margin-left: 3rem;font-size: 15px;"><b>Summe </b></span>
    <span class="pull-right">{{OrderSum}}€</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 3rem;color:#7d7d7d;">
    <span *ngIf="orderCannotBeDelivered"> Leider kannst Du noch nicht bestellen. wir liefern erst ab einem
        Mindestbestellwert von 15,00 € (exkl. Lieferkosten)</span>
</div>
<div>
    <button style="margin-left:3rem;margin-right: -2px;" [disabled]="this.orderedItems.length < 1"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" (click)="submitOrder()">Bestellen</button>
</div>
```

now the following div in my html file is conditional div.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 3rem;color:#7d7d7d;">
        <span *ngIf="orderCannotBeDelivered"> Leider kannst Du noch nicht bestellen. wir liefern erst ab einem
            Mindestbestellwert von 15,00 € (exkl. Lieferkosten)</span>
    </div>
```

it means user is allowed to order only after certain amount.

Here it is how it looks when the conditional text is displayed.

[![Div with amount less than 15
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGjAZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGjAZ.png)

And this is how it looks when conditional text is not anymore there.

[![cart div shrinked
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qToIu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qToIu.png)

i wanted to provide code but somehow Stackblitz is giving me error. I hope the given details are enough. 
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You might want to strip the code you provided to only the css and html part that has to do with the problem

Comment: Without your CSS this will be hard to figure out.

Comment: i do not have any external css for the cart div,  all the styles are directly used in the html file.

Comment: Did you try just removing the class name? It doesn't seem to be needed there - casting a prediction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you only have the option to use `style` attribute tags to modify css. In the first line of your provided HTML code you have

```
position: fixed
```

which I'd change to

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

So this would scroll down, even when the left (main) content has a bigger height.

Therefore the first line of your html should be changed to:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="position: sticky; top: 0; margin-right: 6ex; width: 100%">
```

Notice that I also added `width: 100%`, because you described with both your images that this is conditional with content.

Also notice that the parent element should have been set to `position: relative` (you didn't provide the code of the parent element).

If I understood something wrong, please try to explain it to me again and I will update my answer accordingly.